# Juntar objetos com valores iguais com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, objetos

Tenho um array de objetos. Quero juntar os objetos que tenham valores semelhantes usando JavaScript.

```
const teste = [
{ Hora: '23:49:08.277',
    CodigoDoPiloto: '038',
    Piloto: 'F.MASSA',
    Volta: '1\t\t',
    TempoDaVolta: '1:02.852',
    VelocidadeMediaDaVolta: '44,275\r' },
  { Hora: '23:49:10.858',
    CodigoDoPiloto: '033',
    Piloto: 'R.BARRICHELLO',
    Volta: '1\t\t',
    TempoDaVolta: '1:04.352',
    VelocidadeMediaDaVolta: '43,243\r' },
  { Hora: '23:50:11.447',
    CodigoDoPiloto: '038',
    Piloto: 'F.MASSA',
    Volta: '2\t\t',
    TempoDaVolta: '1:03.170',
    VelocidadeMediaDaVolta: '44,053\r' }

]
```

Quero que fique desta maneira:

```
newTeste = [
   {Hora: '23:49:08.277',
    CodigoDoPiloto: '038',
    Piloto: 'F.MASSA',
    Volta: '1\t\t',
    TempoDaVolta: '1:02.852',
    VelocidadeMediaDaVolta: '44,275\r',
  **Hora: '23:50:11.447',
    Volta: '2\t\t',
    TempoDaVolta: '1:03.170',
    VelocidadeMediaDaVolta: '44,053\r'}**,

   { Hora: '23:49:10.858',
    CodigoDoPiloto: '033',
    Piloto: 'R.BARRICHELLO',
    Volta: '1\t\t',
    TempoDaVolta: '1:04.352',
    VelocidadeMediaDaVolta: '43,243\r' }
]
```

Quero fazer isso dinamicamente:

if(teste.Piloto === teste.Piloto){
????
}

Comment: Você quer unir se **todos** os valores forem iguais ou somente se os **pilotos** forem iguais?

Comment: Somente se os pilotos forem iguais. Se iguais adicionar os outros elementos no mesmo objeto.

Comment: Mas nesse caso haverá perda de dados, já que um objeto não pode ter duas chaves iguais, mesmo que com valores diferentes. Por exemplo, no JavaScript, isso é inválido: `{ a: 25, b: 50 }`. Ademais, o resultado que você espera (de acordo com a pergunta) está incorreto levando em conta essa norma do JS, já que os objetos compartilham mais de uma propriedade com chaves iguais.

Comment: Entendi, obrigada.

Comment: A resposta colocada responde à sua pergunta? Se sim, considere aceitá-la.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme mencionado [nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/400901/juntar-objetos-com-valores-iguais-com-javascript/400906#comment786911_400901), no JavaScript, você não pode criar um objeto que tenha duas propriedades que compartilham a mesma chave. Por exemplo:

```js
console.log({
  name: 'Unknown',
  name: 'Luiz Felipe',
  age: 16
});

// Note que a chave `name` que continha "Unknown" sumiu.
```

Se você fizer isso, nenhum erro será lançado, mas você **perderá dados silenciosamente**, de modo que somente a última chave definida será mantida.

Portanto, a não ser que você desejar um *output* diferente, o mencionado na pergunta é impossível de ser alcançado usando JavaScript.

Não deixe de procurar saber mais sobre [objetos em JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabalhando_com_Objetos).