# Como aplainar um objeto aninhado que pode conter chaves repetidas em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, objetos

Estou tentando transformar um array de objetos no qual cada elemento é assim:

```
{
  id: 1,
  maxiTempo: 30,
  todos: {
    contar: 2,
    porcentagem: 1
  },
  perdeu: {
    contar: 4,
    porcentagem: 1.3
  },
  ganhou: {
    contar: 26,
    porcentagem: 0.9
  }
}
```

Para algo como:

```
{
  id: 1,
  maxiTempo: 30,
  todosContar: 2,
  todosPorcentagem: 1,
  perdeuContar: 4,
  perdeuPorcentagem: 1.3,
  ganhouContar: 26,
  ganhouPorcentagem: 0.9
}
```

Eu estou usando esta função recursiva para deixar os objetos no mesmo nível:

```
let flatten = (obj, final = {}) => {
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object' && obj[key] != null) {
      flatten(obj[key], final)
    } else {
      final[key] = obj[key]
    }
  }
  return final
}
```

Só que eu acho que, como dentro de `ganhou` e `perdeu` tem o mesmos nomes `contar` e `porcentagem`, ele ignora e eu recebo isto:

```
{
  contar: 26,
  id: 1,
  maxiTempo: 30,
  porcentagem: 0.19696969696969696
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O buraco é um pouco mais em baixo. Note que você quer "aplainar" um objeto que pode conter, nos diversos níveis de aninhamento, chaves repetidas. E, conforme expliquei [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400906/69296), em JavaScript, um objeto *não* pode possuir duas propriedades com a mesma chave.

Ou seja, é exatamente o que você supôs:

> Só que eu acho que, como dentro de `ganhou` e `perdeu` tem o mesmos nomes `contar` e `porcentagem`, ele ignora [...]

O seu código realiza o "aplanamento" corretamente. O problema é que não cria nomes distintos para cada propriedade aninhada. Ou seja, uma mesma chave pode ser utilizada várias vezes (como de fato está acontecendo). E, nesse caso, ocorre uma *perda* de dados, já que as propriedades são sobrescritas de forma silenciosa, de modo que somente a última prevalecerá.

Uma opção para resolver isso é passar o nome da propriedade *atual* como terceiro argumento da função `flatten`:

```js
function flatten(obj, final = {}, baseKey = '') {
  for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    const givenKey = !baseKey ? key : baseKey + ucfirst(key);

    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object' && obj[key] !== null) {
      flatten(obj[key], final, givenKey);
    } else {
      final[givenKey] = obj[key];
    }
  }
  return final;
}

function ucfirst(str) {
  return str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
}

const original = {
  id: 1,
  maxiTempo: 30,
  todos: {
    contar: 2,
    porcentagem: 1
  },
  perdeu: {
    contar: 4,
    porcentagem: 1.3
  },
  ganhou: {
    contar: 26,
    porcentagem: 0.9,
    testNest: {
      ok: true
    }
  }
};

console.log(flatten(original));
```

<sub>Note que criei uma função `ucfirst` para capitalizar os nomes corretamente. Repare também que preferi não utilizar o `for..in` (em favor de `Object.keys` – uma das várias alternativas) para evitar a situação potencialmente indesejável de se ler uma propriedade enumerável advinda de definição descuidadosa na cadeia prototípica.</sub>

---

Por curiosidade pessoal, acabei fazendo uma outra alternativa eliminando a recursão, que *pode ser problemática* porque a maioria das implementações do JavaScript [não otimizam recursão em cauda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/427564/69296) e vão empilhando as chamadas até um eventual e catastrófico estouro.

```js
function flatten(obj) {
  const final = {};
  const queue = [['', obj]];

  while (queue.length) {
    const [baseKey, currentObj] = queue.pop();

    for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(currentObj)) {
      const givenKey = !baseKey ? key : baseKey + ucfirst(key);

      if (isObject(val)) {
        queue.push([givenKey, val]);
      } else {
        final[givenKey] = val;
      }
    }
  }

  return final;
}

function ucfirst(str) {
  return str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
}

function isObject(val) {
  return typeof val === 'object' && val !== null;
}

const original = {
  id: 1,
  maxiTempo: 30,
  todos: {
    contar: 2,
    porcentagem: 1
  },
  perdeu: {
    contar: 4,
    porcentagem: 1.3
  },
  ganhou: {
    contar: 26,
    porcentagem: 0.9,
    testNest: {
      ok: true
    }
  }
};

console.log(flatten(original));
```

---

E para transformar cada elemento do array, basta realizar um mapeamento. Pode utilizar um `for` que chama a função `flatten` ou utilizar o próprio [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Vale observar também que os dois códigos acima *não suportam* estruturas cíclicas de objetos.

Comment: caramba, eu entendi o que vc explicou. Excelente resposta, muito obrigada!!! Só queria tirar mais uma dúvida se vc me permitir. Se eu passar meu objeto com apenas um item na sua funcao, ele vai  "achatar" corretamente, conforme vc mostrou mas e se for um array de objetos? ele vai achatar tudo em um unico item? Vou editar meu exemplo pra explicar melhor.

Comment: @Isa, de nada! Eu coloquei uma observação sobre isso no final da resposta. Uma forma para se fazer isso é iterar sobre cada elemento do array e fazer a operação individualmente. Talvez a forma mais simples de se fazer isso seja utilizar o `map`, assim: `const myNewArray = myArray.map((obj) => flatten(obj));`.

Comment: me ajudou muito mesmo!!!

Comment: Excelente resposta!!!!!